# Get second level domain with regexp in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to search through an index in my database which is elasticsearch and I want to search for domains contains a second level domain `(sld)` but it returns me None.

here is what I've done so far:

```
sld = "smth"
query = client.search(
    index = "x",
    body = {
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "site_domain.keyword": fr"*\.{sld}\.*"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

EDIT:
I think the problem is with the regex I wrote

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could give us some sample document you would like to match, and maybe the index mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

```
GET /so_regex_url/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "site_domain": ".*api\\.[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+"
    }
  }
}
```

This regex will match `api.google.com` but won't `google.com`.
You should watch out for the [reserved characters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-reserved-characters) such as `.`

It require proper escape sequence.

## To understand

First let's talk about the pattern your are looking for.
You want to match every url that as a given subdomain.

#### 1. Check the subdomain string exist in the url

Something like `.*<subdomain>.*` will work. `.*` means `any char` in any quantity.

#### 2. Check it is a subdomain

A subdomain in a url looks like `<subdomain>.<domain>.<top level domain>`

You need to make sure that your subdomain has a `.` between both domain and top domain

Something like `.*<subdomain>.*\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+` will work `[a-z]+`
means at least one character between `a` to `z` and because `.` has a special meaning you need to escape it with `\`

This will match `https://<subdomain>.google.com`, but won't `https://<subdomain>.com`

/!\ This is a naive implementation.
`https://<subdomain>.1234.com` won't match has neither `1`, `2` ... exist in `[a-z]`

#### 3. Create Elastic DSL

I am performing the request on the `text` field not the `keyword`, this keep my exemple leaner but work the same way.

```
GET /so_regex_url/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "site_domain": ".*api\\.[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+"
    }
  }
}
```

You may have noticed the `\\` it is explained in the [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/escaping-special-characters-in-regex/173071) it is because the payload travel in a json it also needs to escape that.

#### 4. Python implementation

I imagine it should be

```
sld = "smth"
query = client.search(
    index = "x",
    body = {
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "site_domain.keyword": `.*{sld}\\.[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+`
            }
        }
    }
)
```